# Create node in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have a query I am working on neo4j making my first queries in Cypher, I noticed that when the graph is generated, when establishing the names of the properties, the generated graph only shows the id, to save this difficulty I noticed that for example for a person node instead of placing the property nom (with this name the problem already mentioned is presented) I put name and in that case if I can see the node, attached image. Why does this happen?

```
CREATE (Peter:Persona {nombre:'Peter Sagan', fechanac:'26-01-1990', pais:'Slovaquia'})
```

[image]

```
CREATE (Peter:Person {name:'Peter Sagan', fechanac:'26-01-1990', pais:'Slovaquia'})
```

[image]
I want to be able to establish my own names of nodes and properties and that in the graph view the textual value of the first property appears. How do I do it?

I hope you understand my query from now thank you very much :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0):

The [Neo4j Browser UI Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) should be helpful in learning how to use the neo4j browser.

The neo4j browser allows you to change the caption for each node label. If you click the red `Persona(1)` button at the top of the result panel, you will see several options appear at the bottom, including the available Captions. You can then select the caption you want to use for all `Persona` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on a node for which node you want to change the view.
2. Go to the top as shown in the image and click the label
3. Then you can select the color, size and the caption listed.

[image]